# Tratamento de erros em consulta

Tags: php

Como posso fazer tratamento de erros neste cenário e caso haja erros, por exemplo na conexão ou na declaração, apresentá-los na tela?

**retornaCliente.php**

```
<?php 

        $hostname="localhost";  
        $username="USUARIO";  
        $password="SENHA";  
        $db = "Nome_DB";  
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

    $assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $buscar = $pdo->prepare('SELECT NOME_LOJA FROM lojas WHERE NOME_LOJA LIKE ? ORDER BY NOME_LOJA ASC');
    $buscar->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

    while ($results = $buscar->fetch())
    {
        $data[] = $results['NOME_LOJA'];
    }


    //SQL para selecionar os registros
    $result_msg_cont = $pdo->prepare('SELECT assunto FROM mensagens_contatos WHERE assunto LIKE ? ORDER BY assunto ASC LIMIT 7');
    $result_msg_cont->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

    while ($row_msg_cont = $result_msg_cont->fetch())
    {
        $data[] = $row_msg_cont['assunto'];
    }


    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
  ............
  .............
  <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto">
  </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#assunto").autocomplete({
                source: 'retornaCliente.php' 
            });
        });

    </script>
    ...............
    ...............
```

> O tratamento que usei

```
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        exit("Erro na conexão com a base de dados");

    }
```

> mas a dificuldade é mostrar alguma mensagem na tela

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83159/discussion-on-question-by-leo-caracciolo-tratamento-de-erros-em-consulta)

Comment: @Manieiro, entendi e vou seguir essa orientação, só me explica quais os inconvenientes/problemas dessas longas discussões nos comentários.

Comment: O sistema sempre sinaliza quando ocorre. Está fugindo do objetivo do site que é ter perguntas e respostas, quando tem vários comentários é porque ou a pergunta ou a resposta não estão bons e precisa de discussão demais. Comentar aqui ou ali pra ajudar em algum ponto obscuro é normal, mas quando vai tendo muito é porque tem algo errado e o sistema manda um moderador intervir para não virar fórum.

Answer (score 3):

> A resposta para esta pergunta está no  [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xm98d2wy/) do @Sam indicado no comentário dele e na indicação do SOen do @Bacco. Mas como esses links poderão vir a inexistir futuramente, vou colocar a solução aqui.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#assunto" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "retornaCliente.php",
                data: { query: request.term},
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  //  coloque aqui a mensagem que quiser
                  //$("...").modal('show'); 
                  //alert (...); 
                  //exibir numa div                   
                },
              dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    });   
});
```

PHP

```
$assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'query', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Mas o lance é esse mesmo. A função do `source` é muito restrita e não permite tratar erros.

Comment: @sam, hahaha, a galera de Brasilia anda meio desacreditada! Mas fácil acreditarem na minha versão. :)

Comment: @sam vou dormir, amanhã pé na estrada, volto segunda-feira, abraço!

Comment: Grande abraço irmão. Boa viagem!